# Eureka server is not able to start with error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/config/ConfigurationManager

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have just started learning eureka discovery server. I have created the base spring boot application using spring initializer. I have added enable eureka annotation and trying to start the application.
it is thorowing below error.

```
o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Cannot bootstrap eureka server :
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/config/ConfigurationManager
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerBootstrap.initEurekaEnvironment(EurekaServerBootstrap.java:112) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerBootstrap.contextInitialized(EurekaServerBootstrap.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration.lambda$start$0(EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration.java:70) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.netflix.config.ConfigurationManager
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
... 4 common frames omitted
```

POM.xml file content:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.learn</groupId>
<artifactId>discovery-server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>discovery-server</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>    
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
</properties> 
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

content of application.properties file is:

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Comment: Can you post the `pom.xml` file and the `application.properties/yml` file?

Comment: i have updated the question with the details.